# How ssl certificates are handled in CNAME mapped domains?

Tags: ssl, cname

I observed a site example.com has a cname mapping with mysite.com. Both example.com and mysite.com have ssl certificates.

Correct if I am wrong?

When a browser tries to connect https://example.com it checks DNS and finds it has cname mapping with mysite.com and connect to mysite.com web server directly.

When I observed browser it has ssl certificate for example.com domain. I am  facing problem in understanding this case.

If request did not go to example.com web server how could browser get ssl certificate of example.com
 or my cname mapping understanding is wrong?

or  example.com private and public keys are shared with mysite.com webserver ?

Answer (score 6):

DNS and TLS operate completely independent of each other.

TLS is used, among other things like encryption, to verify the identity of a server against its FQDN (Fully qualified domain name). This is done by checking whether the server in question is able to present a certificate, containing the FQDN, signed by a trusted certification authority (CA).

DNS is used to resolve host names to IP addresses, in order to establish network connections (like TCP connections) on a lower layer. How this resolution takes place is completely transparent to other components, like TLS. It does not matter whether the name resolution involves `A`, `AAAA`, or the mentioned `CNAME` record - in our context the input is always a single hostname, the output is always one (or more) IP addresses. Intermediate results, like `CNAME` mappings, are essentially discarded once name resolution is done.

This means that the TLS client *always* uses the FQDN initially requested by the user, regardless of any `CNAME` mappings, to verify the certificate. How to present a valid certificate is up to the server - sticking to your example, the server behind FQDN `mysite.com` will have to present a certificate valid for `example.com` in order for the client to accept it. How the private/public key of this certificate is generated, and whether it is shared with other certificates or servers, does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

We would have to explicitly attach the SSL certificates of both the domains to the webserver/load balancer for both the domains to support HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this, it's useful to be aware of and understand SNI

> When multiple websites are hosted on one server and share a single IP
> address, and each website has its own SSL certificate, the server may
> not know which SSL certificate to show when a client device tries to
> securely connect to one of the websites. This is because the SSL/TLS
> handshake occurs before the client device indicates over HTTP which
> website it's connecting to.
>
> Server Name Indication (SNI) is designed to solve this problem. SNI is
> an extension for the TLS protocol (formerly known as the SSL
> protocol), which is used in HTTPS. It's included in the TLS/SSL
> handshake process in order to ensure that client devices are able to
> see the correct SSL certificate for the website they are trying to
> reach. The extension makes it possible to specify the hostname, or
> domain name, of the website during the TLS handshake, instead of when
> the HTTP connection opens after the handshake.

From: https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/learning/ssl/what-is-sni/